# Xamarin Forms Tags in CarouselView

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using the new [CarouselView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView) control in my app to display a collection of text/articles. Each article in the collection also contains a string array of text that I refer to as tags. I would like to display these tags horizontally within the carouselview using a control that allows databinding. The expected look should be something like this just below the main text:
[Expected look of tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RAA1.png)

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: Each view can have a global variable called "Tittle" or "Tag" and you can access this in all your code: `public string Tag1 = "Tag 1";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first the good/bad news: the `ListView` would allow you to present a bindable set of tags, but unfortunately it does not currently support a `Horizontal` orientation, so it wouldn't meet your needs.

The next best thing would be a horizontal `StackLayout` contained within a `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
  <StackLayout x:Key="tags" Orientation="Horizontal">
  </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And populate that StackLayout with data from the ViewModel when the binding context or that property changes. The example below populates the StackLayout with `Label` views that are styled up using a style named "TagStyleName".

```
// Note: If this code doesn't work, someone else wrote it. 
protected override OnBindingContextChanged() {
  var vm = this.BindingContext as MyViewModelClass;
  if (vm == null) return;
  vm.PropertyChanged += (o, e) => {
    if (e.PropertyName == "Tags") {
      WatchTagsForChanges();
      RefreshTags();
    }
  };
}

private void WatchTagsForChanges() {
  var vm = this.BindingContext as MyViewModelClass;
  if (vm == null) return;

  vm.Tags.CollectionChanged += (o, e) => RefreshTags();
}

private void RefreshTags() {
  var vm = this.BindingContext as MyViewModelClass;
  if (vm == null) return;

  this.tags.Children.Clear()
  foreach (var tag in vm.Tags) {
    this.tags.Children.Add(new Label{ Text = tag, Style = "TagStyleName" }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution had occurred to me before, however I shelved it as a "PLAN B" since I was looking for a solution that could be **bindable within the carouselview** to avoid delays in loading children when the carousel was swiped. I came across this [link] (https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/blob/master/TagEntryView/README.md). I've not had much success and due to time constraints on the project, I have now used "Plan B". Hence, your response is an answer.